# Removing border from JTextArea

Tags: java, swing, border, jtextarea

Hello i'm having a problem where even though i set `JTextArea1.setBorder(null);` or `jTextArea1.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder());` my JTextArea will still have a bevel border (top and left side - thick, bottom and right side - thin). Is there any reason why this is not working? i want absolutely no border of any kind on this text area.

Here is some of my code:

```
jTextArea1 = new javax.swing.JTextArea();

jTextArea1.setEditable(false);
            jTextArea1.setColumns(20);
            jTextArea1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Monospaced", 0, 6)); // NOI18N
            jTextArea1.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(29, 209, 32));
            jTextArea1.setLineWrap(true);
            jTextArea1.setRows(20);
            jTextArea1.setText("...");
            jTextArea1.setWrapStyleWord(true);
            jTextArea1.setAutoscrolls(false);
            jTextArea1.setBorder(null);
            jTextArea1.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder());
            jTextArea1.setOpaque(false);
            jTextArea1.setCursor(new java.awt.Cursor(java.awt.Cursor.DEFAULT_CURSOR));
            jScrollPane1.setViewportView(jTextArea1);
```

Comment: Hello Andrew, you solved my problem! the border was coming from the scroll pane and when i set the borders to empty they disappeared. If you want, i could accept a submitted answer from you with the solution :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The border comes from the **scroll pane,** not the text area.

Another tip:

```
new java.awt.Font("Monospaced", 0, 6)
```

- Change `"Monospaced"` to `Font.MONSPACED` for compile time checking.
- Change `0` to `Font.PLAIN` both for compile time checking ***&*** to be more informative to anyone that needs to look at or work on the code later.

So it would best be:

```
new java.awt.Font(Font.MONSPACED, Font.PLAIN, 6)
```